# How to program voice modem?

Tags: windows, modem, tapi

I'm looking into writing a small custom app for a small business that can utilize a voice modem on Windows to pick up a phone call and play a customized voice message based on time of call.

The API on Windows that controls modems is TAPI, but it seems complex and low level that I'm not sure I can complete the app in time.

Any higher level API or software component I can use to accomplish what I need?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to look at 3rd party libraries for this. A quick google search turned [this one](https://www.traysoft.com/add-tapi-telephony-library) up (though I've never used it).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what programming language you need, but I found many projects that may have elements you are looking for on [CodeProject.com](https://www.codeproject.com) and [SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net).  I could make suggestions from the sites, but perhaps it would be better to leave it to you, as you know which project would best meet your needs.  Doing a search on TAPI or telephony gave a lot of results, but I didn’t seen an already made project doing what you described above.

I hope these suggestions help you make your deadline, good luck.